# Configurable product how do I use different barcode with each variation?

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product

I am a bit confused about the use of a barcode within our Magento implements. Hopefully someone can kindly point me to the right direction.

1. Currently, in our shop we are using unique barcode for each product even for each variation. Not sure if this is a wrong way to manage stock, feel free to advise.
2. We are using the SKU field for the unique barcode field. Or shall we use a custom field for that?
3. Now, we were told in Magento we can use configurable product to have variations. So, we went ahead and created that with some associated products. But for each associated product there might be more than one quantity for each variation. For example, for x product of red colour and small size we have 3 copies. Magento only allows for one SKU/barcode to be assigned for 1 such copy. But you can't add 3 different SKU/barcode for those 3 copies.  How would you then assign unique barcode to those copies?

See screenshot:
[image]
(see there is only one field for SKU, but we have 3 quantities for the same variation. Are we meant to use the same SKU/barcode for those 3 copies?

Comment: Hi, @oli.chowdhury Required the same condition as you asked here, do you have figure out if can provide me will be helpful, thanks in advance

Comment: @vibhu, I think the way you can solve this is by having the same bar code for each of the copies and when you sell them based on the quantity magento will know how many remain in the stock. So, if you have 3 copies each 3 copies should have the same barcode assigned to them. When you sell one the inventory should update to show 2 remaining. I hope it helps but if you do find anything else please feel free to share in this thread. Good luck